# Menu is hidden behind layout div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The menu in the north region of the layout is not visible. It has been hidden under layout. The problem may be in CSS part, which i tried but unable to resolve it.

Please refer jsfiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/4QbqY/

```
<div class="ui-layout-north">
    <div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="home.html">File <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="aa.html">New</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="aa.html">Open</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li>
                <a href="products.html">Action <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="products.html#chair">Edit      <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Undo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Redo</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cut</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Copy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Paste</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div class="ui-layout-west" id="testdata">
</div>

<div class="ui-layout-south">
    This is the south pane
</div>

<div class="ui-layout-east">
    This is the east pane
</div>

<div class="ui-layout-center">
    This is the center pane
</div>
```

Comment: pass the  value of z-index:3;

Comment: On which element i need to try this @VikasGautam Im not that much strong on css part. so only i shared the jsfiddle. i tried on li:hover > div which doesn't work

Comment: solved by <div class="ui-layout-north" onmouseover="myLayout.allowOverflow('north')"> or update nav > ul > li > div, nav > ul > li > div ul > li > div with:

 z-index:3;

and add this style:

.ui-layout-north
{
    position:initial !important;
    z-index:3 !important;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of minutes.
Here's the result that you wanted.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QbqY/24/)

**HTML**

Just add this in your north layout `onmouseover="myLayout.allowOverflow('north')"`

```
<div class="ui-layout-north" onmouseover="myLayout.allowOverflow('north')">
```

Reference:

http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html

Comment: Just now i noted, i don't know how it has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

update nav > ul > li > div, nav > ul > li > div ul > li > div with:

```
 z-index:3;
```

and add this style:

```
.ui-layout-north
{
    position:initial !important;
    z-index:3 !important;
}
```

[jsfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4QbqY/22/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it work as expected. But still a_enriquez posted before u and his post also solve my problem. i had given +upvote for you. Thanks a lot for your time.